# Where's the code spending 95% of its time?

Tags: resharper, blazor-server-side, dottrace

I ran dotTrace to profile my Blazor Server app. Below is the hotspot output.Under All Calls 100% it is only showing about 5% of the time. Where's the rest of the time being spent?

[image]

Comment: Click on the icon to the left of 100%.

Comment: @IgorAkhmetov Oh, the icon between the > and the number - that showed it. Unfortunately 60% is [no callstack] so doesn't help much. But at least I now know what. thanks